# Git multiline trailer with empty lines (is this a bug?)

Tags: git

So, git trailers (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) supports multi-line trailers by "folding" them, meaning that subsequent lines start with one space to indicate that they still belong to the current trailer.

The documentation says:

> When reading trailers, there can be whitespaces after the token, the
> separator and the value. There can also be whitespaces inside the
> token and the value. The value may be split over multiple lines with
> each subsequent line starting with whitespace, like the "folding" in
> RFC 822.

My problem is that `git interpret-trailers --parse` fails if such a multi-line trailer contains an empty line.

I'm trying to add a trailer that contains one or more empty lines. These empty lines are properly folded however, they contain one space (so this is equivalent to the PGP signature that is added to the commit header, which also contains an empty line, that is folded however)

But if I do that, `git interpret-trailers --parse` just outputs nothing.

```
$ echo "Test" > test.txt
$ git interpret-trailers --where end --if-exists addIfDifferent --trailer "SingleLineTrailer: This is a single line trailer" --in-place test.txt
$ git interpret-trailers --where end --if-exists addIfDifferent --trailer "MultiLineTrailer: This is"$'\n a folded multi-line\n trailer' --in-place test.txt
```

contents of test.txt is now:

```
$ cat test.txt
Test

SingleLineTrailer: This is a single line trailer
MultiLineTrailer: This is
 a folded multi-line
 trailer
```

and parsing works (it parses multiple lines to a single line, which is unexpected, but at least does something):

```
$ git interpret-trailers --parse test.txt
SingleLineTrailer: This is a single line trailer
MultiLineTrailer: This is a folded multi-line trailer
```

However, now I'm adding a multi-line trailer that contains a free line (properly folded using a space however):

```
$ git interpret-trailers --where end --if-exists addIfDifferent --trailer "MultiLineTrailer: This is"$'\n a folded multi-line\n trailer which\n \n contains an\n empty line' --in-place test.txt
```

which results, as expected, in the following content:

```
$ cat test.txt
Test

SingleLineTrailer: This is a single line trailer
MultiLineTrailer: This is
 a folded multi-line
 trailer
MultiLineTrailer: This is
 a folded multi-line
 trailer which

 contains an
 empty line
```

however, running `git interpret-trailers --parse` results in no output (but exit code is 0):

```
$ git interpret-trailers --parse test.txt
$ echo $?
0
```

git version is `git version 2.30.0.windows.2`

So, is this a bug in git or is this behaviour expected?

Comment: This is a good question. The Git mailing list has had a lot of discussion about the trailer code; it is probably worth searching it to see if there are claims one way or the other.

Comment: With git v2.35 it Does also not work.

Comment: OP ended up asking about it on the Git mailing list. Thread: https://lore.kernel.org/git/CALz+XyW+XU++58eEYm5=jxTckK-VuuPoA-ecj4QCZw1o44JFUQ@mail.gmail.com/

Answer (score 1):

This was marked as a “will not fix”/“not a bug” on the Git mailing list
thread.

#### Context

OP ended up filing a [bug report](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CALz+XyW+XU++58eEYm5=jxTckK-VuuPoA-ecj4QCZw1o44JFUQ@mail.gmail.com/) to the Git mailing list.

A [quick patch](https://lore.kernel.org/git/YCwJ8tORQg2Air4r@nand.local/) was proposed as a fix for the issue. But then
Hamano [pointed out](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqmtw3pzu3.fsf@gitster.c.googlers.com/) that the proposed fix adds complications.

[Christian Couder](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAP8UFD1QG_b6ax-HodLRRcdLKgWJhPDghjLfjnyan1Zi80en7A@mail.gmail.com/) did not want to relax the current
blank-line-before-trailers rule:

> So I thought that blank lines should not appear in the trailers. And
> if any appears, it means that the trailers should start after the last
> blank line. This might actually have been already relaxed a bit.

[One of the](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqr1k3w1g7.fsf@gitster.g/#t) two terminal emails in the thread were by Hamano,
and indirectly concluded that this was not a bug:

> The next step is to find out if there is anything unclear in the
> description of the current behaviour in that paragraph that may have
> resulted in the report of the "bug" that turned out to be a non-bug.